# Why is this SPF record being reported as invalid?

Tags: email, spf, email-bounces

I've set up my SPF record at improvedemployees.com as follows:

```
v=spf1 a mx ptr ip4:84.40.9.177 mx ip4:84.40.9.11 ~all
```

I've set up my SPF record at affiliatewebdesigners.com to point to using improvedemployees.com as this is the reverse lookup name of the server. The SPF for affiliatewebdesigners.com is as follows:

```
v=spf1 a mx ptr ip4:84.40.9.177 mx ip4:84.40.9.11 include:improvedemployees.com ~all
```

I'm still getting bounced emails unless I'm on a whitelist and I can't figure out why. I've tried to analyse my SPF record using mxtoolbox:

http://mxtoolbox.com/domain/improvedemployees.com/?source=findmonitors

[image]

This error seems pretty useless. Can anyone help me figure out where I'm going wrong?

Comment: Doesn't seem to be the issue, but you've got "mx" specified twice in both of them. Putting it into http://www.kitterman.com/spf/validate.html shows me an error of "unknown mechanism ~all" which doesn't make sense to me.

Comment: Thanks for that link and spotting mx twice in there. When I validate with that link it seems valid for me now.

Comment: Having said that, it was the 'unknown mechanism ~all' error I was getting previously when I used another tool other than mxtoolbox - might have been this kitterman one. Maybe once the new SPF records have been updated without the additional mx it will be considered valid.

Comment: On a slightly unrelated note, RFC7208 (the latest SPF RFC) discourages using the "ptr" mechanism for a number of reasons. It's slow and prone to errors for starters, but combined with the void lookup limitations of RFC7208 it can also cause difficulty enforcing your SPF policy.

Comment: MX-Toolbox does not show an error anymore, has the issue been resolved with the hint from ceejayoz, @dave-hilditch?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The right format for SPF record would be:

`domain.com.  IN TXT "v=spf1 mx a ip4:mail.domain.com ~all"`

or

`domain.com.  IN TXT "v=spf1 mx a ip4:mail.domain.com a:anotherdomain.com ~all"`

There are some online SPF Record Generator out there that can help you with creating SPF Record.

Answer (score 1):

You've got "mx" specified twice in both of them.

> v=spf1 a **mx** ptr ip4:84.40.9.177 **mx** ip4:84.40.9.11 ~all
>
> v=spf1 a **mx** ptr ip4:84.40.9.177 **mx** ip4:84.40.9.11 include:improvedemployees.com ~all